# How to get the same byte Array after stored it as String?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, text-compression

I have used Java code to compress a string to a byte array and then I store this byte array as a string in Cloud database. The decrypted message needs the same byte array which was returned by the compress method. So how to get the same byte array from the stored string.

```
public class Gzip {

    public static byte[] compress(String data) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
        gzip.write(data.getBytes());
        gzip.close();
        byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();
        return compressed;
    }

    public static String decompress(String temp) throws IOException {
        String decodeData =  new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(temp));

        byte[] compressed = decodeData.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        gis.close();
        bis.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Gzip gzip = new Gzip();
        String plaintext = "Although there are many short stories. ";
        byte[] enbyte = gzip.compress(l);
        String enStr = String.valueOf(enbyte);
        // then stored enStr in cloud database
        //how to get same byte array as 'enbyte' from the 'enStr'
        //if you could modify the methods to return and get string this will             //also be helpfull 
         byte[] newbyte = ???? // 
        System.out.println(gzip.decompress(newbyte));
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `decompress()` method you're decoding it from base-64, but in your `compress()` method you are not encoding it as base-64.

Comment: Encoding is not encryption.